# Avoid empty log files getting touched upon invoking Django management command

Tags: python, django, logging

I have logging configured in my project.settings file as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
    [ . . . ],
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'logfile': {
            '()': uniq_logfile,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'logtype': 'global',
        },
    [ . . . ]
}
```

Here is the definition of uniq_logfile:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def uniq_logfile(logtype):
    base = '%s.%s' % (logtype, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%b.%H%M'))
    path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.logs', base)
    return logging.FileHandler(path, 'w')
```

Problem: Whenever I run any `./manage.py <command>`, all handlers are invoked and an empty log file for each handler is touched. For example, if I have 3 handlers defined, and I invoke a `manage.py` command that has only one associated handler, all 3 handlers are invoked (2 empty files are created corresponding to the other two handlers). Is there some setting to avoid doing that?

I am using python v2.7.10 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of Python you're using - in Python 2.6 and later, you can set the `delay` parameter to file handler constructors to avoid opening the files until something is actually going to be written to them. See the [`FileHandler` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vinay. I am ok with the file being created, but my problem is that if there are 3 handlers - say logfile1, logfile2, logfile3 - and in some management command I am only invoking logfile1, even logfile2 and logfile3 get created. I essentially want that only the relevant logfile be created.